# reCAPTCHA-like Web Service in other Languages

Tags: internationalization, captcha, recaptcha, localization

Is there a CAPTCHA web service like [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/) that supports languages other than English?

It would be nice to have localized CAPTCHAs for non-English users.

Answer (score 8):

recaptcha support other languages see link

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html

```
English en 
Dutch nl 
French fr 
German de 
Portuguese pt 
Russian ru 
Spanish es 
Turkish tr
```

use it like  :

```
<script>
var RecaptchaOptions = {       
   lang : 'fr'
};
</script>
```

if the languages you looking is not supported ,
you can build your own translation ,

look in this link :

http://wiki.recaptcha.net/index.php/I18n

Comment: @IrishChieftain: Indeed, the UI messages are translated but the actual CAPTCHA image still shows up in English.

Comment: This is so sad - I'll have to turn to another service

Answer (score 0):

There you go: [BotDetect](http://captcha.com/localizations/spanish-captcha.html#argentinian-spanish). Nonetheless, it's not a free service.